# How to make a tf.transform (Tensorflow Transform) encoded dict?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform

I'm trying to get a ["tf.transform encoded dict"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/coders/ExampleProtoCoder) with this **tfx.components.Transform** function.

```
 transform = Transform(
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
    schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'],
    module_file=os.path.abspath(_taxi_transform_module_file),
    instance_name="taxi")
context.run(transform)
```

I need a dict like this: " a dict of the data you load ({feature_name: feature_value})."

**Transform** as mentioned above gives me a TfRecord file. How can i decode it properly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow_transform as tft
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
   NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS = ['PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm', 
   'SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm']
   TARGET_FEATURES = "Species"
   outputs = inputs.copy()
   del outputs['Id']

   for key in NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS:
       outputs[key] = tft.scale_to_0_1(outputs[key])

 
   return outputs
```

Write a module like this i have written one for iris dataset it's simple to understand for your dataset also you can do like this it will be saved as a tfrecord dataset